# Mist dont run when i run geth from command prompt IN MAC

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I want to start rinkeby locally on network .......

When I run geth from command line, it uses datadir folder. While geth is running on I also want to start mist, but it give me error datadir is used by another process.

How I can run both simultaneously

Thanks in Advanced

Comment: Change geth data dir by specifying --datadir then both will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is not clear for me, I'll try to provide general steps to connect geth with Mist.

1. **start geth node:** `geth --datadir="/some/path/to/chaindata_folder" --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*"  --rpcapi "eth,web3,personal,net,miner,admin,debug"`
2. **start Mist in new Terminal tab / window with specified geth.ipc file** (see it geth terminal): `open -a /applications/mist.app/contents/macos/mist --args --rpc "/some/path/to/geth.ipc"`
3. **attach geth.ipc in new Terminal:** `geth attach ipc:"/some/path/to/geth.ipc"`

**/some/path/to/geth.ipc - find in first terminal “IPC endpoint opened:”**

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.....

For mac,


first we have to run 
geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=2048 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" 

and then run 
/Applications/Mist.app/Contents/MacOS/Mist --rpc ~/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth.ipc

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want your mist to use the same datadir as geth.

Try to tell mist to use the geth.ipc file that geth creates, by giving it the  `--rpc "~/geth.ipc"` param when starting it (of course, update that with the actual path to the `geth.ipc` file).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.

Can you help me with, how to start mist from MAC terminal with geth.ipc

Thanks